# confusion on using equation datediff to filter data

Tags: sql, alias, datediff

I'm having trouble writing a query that will use or condition to count the hours that are either 30 or 120 minutes, but I keep getting errors. I used an alias for my equation. What is the correct way to set the or condition for my equation.

--when subjobs went into nips today,  no longer in nips, how long were in nips for

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,begintime, aftertime) difference 






  FROM [ABC].[dbo].[timerecords] (nolock)



  where begintime > '1994-08-11'

  and aftertime is not null
 
  -- you can not use alias
  DATEDIFF(minute,begintime, aftertime) in (30 or 120)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (datediff is a product specific function.)

Comment: The IN  syntax should be `IN (30, 120)`.

Comment: just a random database, since I can't use an alias in or condition, I just put the whole equation in.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your query up as a *derived table*:

```
select * from
(
  SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,begintime, aftertime) difference 
  FROM [ABC].[dbo].[timerecords] (nolock)
  where begintime > '1994-08-11'
    and aftertime is not null
) dt
where difference in (30, 120)
```